# .animate({'left': '0%'}); not working when attached to 3 divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the below code, which is swiping between divs when an image is clicked.

The problem is, is that I want to be able to swipe like so: red > green > blue, but at the moment I can only swipe between the red and green div.

Can anyone give me some guidance here?

Thanks!

```
/* These are the individual divs which are scrolled through */
#left {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
#right {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; 
    right:-105%;
}
#middle {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:-205%;
}
```

JS/JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Scroll all content to the left <---- this way
    $('#scrollRight').click(function(e) {  

            $('.container').animate({'left': '-105%'});             

        });

        //Scroll all content to the right ----> this way
    $('#scrollLeft').click(function(e) {  
    $('.container').animate({'left': '0%'});        

        });         

    //End document ready function.      
    });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
            <!-- You have to add the last div first, so that each div will get added after that...basically so that the div you wich to see first, is in first position -->

            <div id="right">right scroll</div>  
            <div id="middle">left scroll</div>          
            <div id="left">left scroll</div>

    </div>
```

Here is the Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/45g3Le59/

Comment: You mean mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/dhtbjxk3/?

Answer (score 0):

All three DIVS animate at the same time, so you see only two slides being animated... Add a delay between animations.